# Can I add type information to an ActiveAdmin attributes_table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I want to make a table essentially like the `attributes_table`, but with a column showing the type of each field.  I haven't found anything as convenient as `attributes_table(:show_types)` or `attibutes_table do; column :type; ...`.

Is there a way to add such a column to attributes_table?  If so, how?  If not, what's the closest alternative?

Comment: Any solid example of your expected outcome? I don't quite understand what "columns" means in an `attributes_table`. An `attributes_table` in AA means it's a table to show the attributes of a resource object which represents in rows like what you've seen in standard AA configuration. You might configure another table in your show block or render a partial so that you can create a table using your choice of Rails Views template engine.

Comment: Columns, in the HTML table it generates.  Currently it creates a table with two columns: field names, and their values in this record (from ActiveRecord).  I'd like another column in the HTML table that shows the types of those fields.

Answer (score 1):

Defining a custom Arbre component would be the best way to accomplish it, but it would not be trivial. Creating a customized subclass of [`AttributesTable`](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/views/components/attributes_table.rb) would be a good starting point. Modifying the implementations of `row`, and `build_colgroups` would be required at the minimum.

One key thing to note is the component will require a unique builder method name like `attributes_table_with_types_for`.

Comment: This is a step in the right direction .. essentially you would want to add another td here : https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/views/components/attributes_table.rb#L36 with the column information

Comment: Yes, exactly. And add another column in `build_colgroups`.